# Cannot truncate table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, truncate

When I try to truncate the table, i got the error Message as follows,

```
**Cannot truncate table 'Locations' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.**
```

I don't know the query for that..Anyone help me.

Comment: remove all the relations of the table `location` and then try...

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 1):

**Why?**

The reason why is that TRUNCATE removes all the records without individual checking.

So a DELETE FROM Locations will delete each record (and that's what gets logged in the transaction logs), checking that no constraints have been violated.

TRUNCATE TABLE Locations doesn't do this. A single truncate action is performed (and logged) and this is why is is quicker.

See [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1080/deleting-data-in-sql-server-with-truncate-vs-delete-commands/) for more information.

**Workaround**

The easiest way is to delete rather than truncate. But if this has a long execution time, and it is safe to remove constraints, you might want to write a script to drop constraints, truncate table, create constraints.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of - when you truncate the identity column is reset. When you delete it does not. So if you do a delete and the last value was 242, the next value will be 243.

The only way to do the truncate is to delete the relations. Personally - I would just delete instead of deleting all the relations and then putting them back.